# JQuery find the length of string that div can contain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Div, which dosn't have fix height or width. 
the div will contain some text, the length of string not fix. if the String is too long to fit in the div, the text will appear outside the div, what I need is to know how much maximum length of String the div can contain based on it's width and height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are using a fixed width font where all characters are the same width (which is unusual), there is no answer to your question.  How many characters fit in a given width depends upon what the characters are as characters like a "W" are much wider than characters like an "i" in all variable width fonts.

If you are using a fixed width font, then you need to measure how wide a character is in the font and font-size and font-style you're using.  You can then simply divide the width you have by the character width and determine how many characters will fit.

It is possible to measure a fixed width font, by creating a div with no margin, padding or border, setting the style to `position: absolute`, setting the desired font-family and font-size on it and putting one character in the div.  You can then fetch the width of the div by getting it's offsetWidth.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kHHU7/ for a simple example.

Here's a function that measure's the width of a character in a fixed width font:

```
function getCharWidth(fontFamily, fontSize) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
    div.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
    div.style.fontSize = fontSize;
    div.innerHTML = "S";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    var width = div.offsetWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(div);
    return(width);
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y4eZr/

Comment: Well I think you mean fix width font in pixel not fix font size in pixel right?

Comment: I think your right, I did that before with anther application, Thanks I will try hope it will work as i want.

Comment: @AymanSalah - I added code that actually does what I described (measures the width of a char).

Comment: It's actually not true that there is no answer.  There are jQuery plugins that do this.  See my answer for one.

Comment: @Muhd - With a given string and a given width and a known variable width font and size, one can compute how much will fit.  It involves creating an actual div and measuring the width with varying parts of the string in it.  That is not what I thought the OP was asking and it isn't what they needed because they are using a fixed width font.

Comment: I tried the code by http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/y4eZr/? if I test the code directly from the website it works fine with both upper and lower case, but if I copy the same code to my web site, it shows different width for upper case and lower case. I don't know what is the problem

Comment: @AymanSalah - It sounds to me like you don't really have a fixed width font because "S" and "s" will have the same width in a fixed width font, but not the same width in a variable width font.  But, not much else we can help with without seeing the code that actually causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's better to use css overflow:hidden on div?

Comment: I did used overflow:hidden, the problem in some cased half length of the last visible line will appear, which not good looking

Comment: IE have build-in text-overflow:ellipsis; which adds ... to the cut text

Comment: github.com/sakura-sky/jquery-ellipsis is very slow for long text. as it deletes last character every time until it fit's the div. It's really slow

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the jQuery plugin [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) for handling this.  You don't need to know how long, it will do all the work for you of truncating the text to the appropriate length.

Answer (score 0):

Divider elements are fluid container elements and aren't really designed to do this sort of thing.

The best way I can think of to achieve this is divide the `clientWidth` of the div by the presumed font width.

`var maxChars = div.clientWidth / 5;`