# find the number of string including white-space that can be inserted inside a div of fixed width with a fixed font-size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to know if I could predict the number of strings including white-space that can be inserted inside a div of fixed width and fixed font-size programatically.. I have a divs of diferent width in to which I add names dynamically.. so the width varies based on the some density measures of that name..
I know I can use the css methods like

```
        "white-space", "nowrap"
        "overflow", "hidden"
        "text-overflow", "ellipsis"
```

but I wanna know if I do it using javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it programmatically. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/A6s4h/)

```
var wid = $("div").width();
var allowedChars = parseInt(wid/getCharWidth('Courier New', '10px'));

var div = $("div");
for(var i = allowedChars; i > 0; i--) {
   $(div).append("a");
}

function getCharWidth(fontFamily, fontSize) {
 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.style.position = "absolute";
 div.style.visibility = "hidden";
 div.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
 div.style.fontSize = fontSize;
 div.innerHTML = "S";
 document.body.appendChild(div);
 var width = div.offsetWidth;
 document.body.removeChild(div);
 return(width);
}
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762503/jquery-find-the-length-of-string-that-div-can-contain) link for more information.

Cheers!!!