# How to find the default length of character in <p> tag according to height and width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried to get default length for `<p>` tag in html, It should be display according to the height & width of tag `<p>`.

**For Eg:**

I have this piece of code,

```
<p style="height:300px;width:200px;"> </p>
```

Here, Height is "300" & width is "200". how can i get default character length in this `<p>` tag.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "character length"?

Comment: @Ital Gal Available space in tag <p>...

Comment: @MuraliSharuk Available space means?

Comment: @Patsy Issa : Yeah it should return by font size as well as.

Comment: Characters in a `<p>` tag are not rendered at all. Characters in a `p` element may be rendered, but the example has only one space there. It is unclear whether the question is related to `p` elements at all. And there is no such concept as “default character length”. If you mean average character width, then the answer is that it depends on the font and on the concept of average (which average over which?).

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of helper container (hidden from user). The idea is that you duplicate text in this container (and styles) and measure the width of it.

Consider this example:

```
var $container = $('.container'),
    height = $container.height(),
    width  = $container.width();

$('button').click(function() {
    $container[0].innerHTML += random();
    if (!checkFit($container)) {
        alert(['overflow! max chars ', $container.text().length - 1]);
    }
});

function checkFit($el) {
    var $clone = $el.clone().addClass('clone').appendTo('body');
    return $clone.width() <= width && $clone.height() <= height;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NrkQC/

Comment: Excellent piece of lateral thinking +1

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` is a block level element, and hence it will occupy the width of its container. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Comment: what if `<p>` is assigned width?

Comment: then of course, the new width is assigned. My statement above was for the case when it is not assigned any width - the default

Comment: You anyway don't answer the OP question: how many characters will fit in provided container.

Comment: @theCoder OP has already given this: `<p style="height:300px;width:200px;"> </p>`

Comment: I presume that my assumption holds good that he meant the width  of the tag. See his comment "@Ital Gal Available space in tag <p>."

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't get an exact number because not all characters have the same width. 
[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/bMLVW/1/) each line have 10 characters but they don't have the same length.

You can estimate the space yo got by dividing the total space (200*300) in the font size (say 20px) and get this: 200*300/20 = ~3000

```
<p>
    abcdefghig<br />
    0123456789<br />
    !@#$%^&*()<br />
</p>
```

Look at this: [example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/bMLVW/2/)

You have 20 `1`s and 28 `-` and they both take 1 line, so an exact formula is not realistic. You can only estimate it. If you want to get the best estimation you can try calculating the probability of each character ([see link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency)) and considering each character's width (according to the font-family and font-size) you can estimate the "space" you got.

Comment: So what? providing the font-family, font size, line-height, font-style, etc you can say that in this dimensions will fit only 10 chars, and it this 20. It's quite possible.

Comment: here's the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762503/jquery-find-the-length-of-string-that-div-can-contain

Comment: @Itay Gal hi 3000 means what available character or place

Comment: Estimation of the characters number